# RelationShip BelongsToMany Laravel - Only return withTimeStamps

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I need your help.

I have next models:

```
class Store extends Model {
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'category_by_store','store_id','category_id')->withPivot('refIdInMyStore');
    }
}

class Category extends Model{
public function store()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Store::class, 'category_by_store','category_id','store_id');
    }}
```

So, if I want to retrieve categories from a store I write:

```
$store = Store::find(1);
$categories = $store->categories()
```

But the response is: `{"withTimestamps":false}`

¿What is my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: change `$categories = $store->categories()`  to `$categories = $store->categories`

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are calling it as a function `$store->categories()`. Which would be similar to calling `Categories::where('store_id', $id)` without calling `->get()` to execute the query.

You should call it as an attribute `$categories = $store->categories` instead.

There are many who are against not being explicit about the fact that you are executing a new query because the relationship looks like an attribute.

I have found that it's better for code clarity and likely performance to use the eager loading like this:

```
$store = Store::with('categories')->find(1);
```

I believe this clearly signals that you will be using the categories relationship.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Azeame! I understand now!

Comment: Add some more info on it for you also.